# Why don't Postgresql use a index for a query?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, optimization

I have a huge table as following:

```
CREATE TABLE ticks8888 (
    tick_time timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL,
    trade_day date NOT NULL,
    other_col FLOAT8 NULL,
CONSTRAINT ticks8888_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tick_time) );

CREATE INDEX idx_ticks8888_trade_day ON ticks8888(trade_day);
```

When I do a query `SELECT max(tick_time) FROM ticks8888 WHERE trade_day = to_date('20220106', 'YYYYMMDD')`, it looks like that the index `idx_ticks8888_trade_day` don't take effect at all, and results the query very slow,

while a query `SELECT count(*) FROM ticks8888 WHERE trade_day = to_date('20220106', 'YYYYMMDD')` is very fast, I can see the query plan that says it's using the index `idx_ticks8888_trade_day`.

What is the wrong I did?

Comment: How many records in the table? How many records match the specified date?

Comment: about 60k in 2000k

Comment: You need an index on `(trade_day, tick_time)` to support the `max(tick_time)` query

Answer (score 2):

Like a_horse_with_no_name mentions in the comments, your [index isn't covering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) for your first query that uses `max(tick_time)`, as it's currently defined. Instead you need to define an index on `(trade_day, tick_time)` such that it stores both fields used in your query.

You can verify the different and more performant query plan you'll get by running [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) with your query, before you fix the index and then after.

Comment: Then why is `SELECT count(*) FROM ticks8888 WHERE trade_day = to_date('20220106', 'YYYYMMDD')` very fast? I think the existing index is good enough, but it isn't used, like jjanes' answer suggests.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Because that query only references `trade_day` which is part of OP's original index, so therefore it **is** covered by his original index. Jjanes answer says the same thing as me (albeit with more elaboration), that OP's index isn't used for his query which is because it isn't covering and ergo PostgreSQL doesn't know where the `tick_time` field exists relative to the `trade_day` field. And that using a covering index like suggested should help.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sure thing, no problem!

Answer (score 1):

You told us what plan it is not using, but didn't tell us what plan it is using.  Presumably it is walking down the primary key index until it finds the first tick_time which meets the trade_day condition, which it thinks will happen quickly.

I am assuming that tick_time is always (redundantly) including the trade_day within it.  So that makes them extremely correlated.  But PostgreSQL doesn't know that, it thinks trade_days are randomly scattered along the tick_time axis.  And alas, there is really no way to convince it otherwise.

As the horse with no name mentioned, you would really benefit from an index on `(trade_day, tick_time)`.  That way it can read the max tick_time for a given trade_day directly from the index.